# How to generate a 'label' using a json file in app configuration service?

Tags: json, azure, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to import a json file into Azure app configuration service using cli command:
`az appconfig kv import`.

**Sample json file**

```
{
    "Pss": {
        "account/getall/get": "read",
        "account/setall/put": "write",
        "account/someendpoint/somevalue": "profile"
    }
}
```

I can see below preview in cli

```
Adding:
{"key": "Pss:account/getall/get", "value": "\"read\""}
{"key": "Pss:account/setall/put", "value": "\"write\""}
{"key": "Pss:account/someendpoint/somevalue", "value": "\"profile\""}
```

Labels are created as (No label) in app configuration service.

[image]

Could you please suggest to me what changes need to be done in the json file to generate label values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command will helps you to get the ***label name***:

```
az appconfig kv import --name hkappconfig --label testingLabelName --source file --path /home/hari/Import.json --format json --separator . --content-type "application/json
```

[image]

By adding the attribute `--label labelName` in the Importing az cli command, You will get the label name in the configuration explorer of the app configuration.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: @[Hari Krishna]  Can you please also explain how to add labels to individual keys?  Let's Say I have an app.json file with { "key1" :"value1","label" :"blue"}
and I have 100+ keys in the json file which I have to add to appConfig.

Comment: Hello @Lakshman, Could you please post as a new question!